# Autocomplete hover removing autofill

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to alter the behaviour of autocomplete a little. I've got a mock up here http://jsfiddle.net/ekzMN/6/ which is producing the desired result (a la chrome address bar) - as pictured below (currently case sensitive).

[image]

The problem I'm having is when the autocomplete list is showing and I hover over the items in the list, the input value changes back to the inputted term rather than staying on the adjusted term with autofill. i.e. in the above image it would change from *Hackn [ey, Eastern Cape, South Africa]* to *Hackn*.

I guess it is a bit of default autocomplete behaviour that I need to overide but I can't work it out. I've tried `focus: false` and `blur: false` but to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if I've got the wrong end of the stick, but I'm not seeing this behaviour in your fiddle? When I enter a term in the textbox and hover over the list, nothing changes. The textbox only updates onclick of a list item.

Comment: Yeah sorry, try a case sensative example (I haven't got around to making it incensative yet). If you type in 'Hackn' (note capital H) and wait for a second the input should autofill with the first result. Now hovering over the list should return it to just the inputted term. That is unless there are browser discrepancies. I'm only currently using Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to achieve - that the input text will change based on the hovered item? http://jsfiddle.net/ekzMN/8/ Just override the focus event:

```
focus: function(event, ui){
        $("#location").val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    },
```

If you want the text to always be set to the first index and does not change whenever you hover on the list, you can set it to the first index of the result list.

Comment: Not quite - although this suggestion did lead me to this `focus: function(event, ui) {
        var i = $("#location").val().length;
        $("#location").val(suggestion);
        // Select remaining non inputted value
        $('#location').selectRange(i, suggestion.length);
        return false;
    }` - although this does still feel a bit dirty. There's a flicker of the selected input section when the hover first occurs as well which isn't ideal. Try it http://jsfiddle.net/ekzMN/11/

Comment: I got around this by removing focus state completely and just redifining the search term on open when autofill occured `result.term = suggestion;` http://jsfiddle.net/ekzMN/89/